# Refresh Xaml UI data bind

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, windows-phone-8

I'm working with windows phone apps and my apps getting data from the web service and sometimes when connection is not good there will be error and not showing data so I add one refresh button into my apps and in that apps I'm calling loaddata from mainviewmodel but nothing happen, what's wrong?

```
MainViewModel mv = new MainViewModel();
private void refreshButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     mv.LoadData();
}
```

and here is loadData() in my mainviewmodel.cs

```
public void LoadData()
        {

             Geolocator geolocator = new Geolocator();
            geolocator.DesiredAccuracyInMeters = 50;

            try
            {
                Geoposition position =
                await geolocator.GetGeopositionAsync(
                TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1),
                TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));

                center = new GeoCoordinate(
                        position.Coordinate.Latitude,
                        position.Coordinate.Longitude);

                latitude = position.Coordinate.Latitude;
                longitude = position.Coordinate.Longitude;
                UpdateTransport();
            }
            catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Location is disable in phone settings.");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            this.IsDataLoaded = true;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *guess* DataContext of your page is a `MainViewModel` object. In that case, you should invoke `LoadData` of the DataContext instead of "creating a new `MainViewModel` object then invoke the newly created `MainViewModel's LoadData`". Because the page showing data from it's DataContext. If I guess the situation right, your refresh button code should be about like this :

```
private void refreshButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     var vm = (MainViewModel)this.DataContext;
     vm.LoadData();
}
```

And if you implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged` properly in `MainViewModel` you'll see the page updated.